# Angle modulation spectrum

Tags: frequency, frequency-spectrum, modulation

Is angle modulation spectrum always discrete or this property only holds for periodic modulating signal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will see lines in the spectrum of a phase-modulated signal if there is some periodicity in the modulating signal. If the modulating signal is not periodic, then the power spectrum of the modulated signal will be smooth.

As an example: consider a BPSK signal:

- If the bits used to modulate the waveform are equally likely to be a one or a zero and are uncorrelated with one another, then there is no periodicity in the modulating signal. The power spectrum of a BPSK signal with independent equally-likely bits has a $sinc^2$ shape with no discrete lines.
- If you then changed the data bits to add some repetitive framing data, for instance, causing a pattern of invariant bits in the modulating signal, you will begin to see lines appear due to the deterministic periodicity in the modulated signal.

In practice, one often makes an effort to ensure that bits are equally distributed to ones and zeros without repetitive patterns. Adding a source encoder (e.g. data compression) to your system can help to remove any repetitiveness in your data and whiten the transmitted bitstream.

One caveat to the above, courtesy of Dilip Sarwate's comment below, is duplicated here to make it more visible:

> However, modulating signals such as $\cos(\omega_1 t)+\cos(\omega_2 t)$ where $\omega_1 / \omega_2$ is an irrational number (i.e. no harmonic relationship exists) are not periodic but have lines in the spectrum at $\omega_c \pm m \omega_1$, $\omega_c \pm m \omega_2$, and $\omega_c \pm m \omega_1 \pm n \omega_2$ plus a lot of clutter (smooth spectrum) in between the lines. Here $\omega_c$ denotes the carrier frequency. There are also similar lines (and clutter) near the harmonics of the carrier frequency.

Comment: Jason R's answer is correct in the broad sense and will work in all practical applications.  However, modulating signals such as $\cos(\omega_1t) + \cos(\omega_2t)$ where $\omega_1/\omega_2$ is an irrational number (i.e. no harmonic relationship exists) are _not periodic_ but have lines in the spectrum at $\omega_c \pm m\omega_1$, $\omega_c \pm n\omega_2$ and $\omega_c \pm m\omega_1 \pm n\omega_2$ plus a lot of clutter (smooth spectrum) in between the lines.  Here $\omega_c$ denotes the carrier frequency. There are also similar lines (and clutter) near the _harmonics_ of the carrier frequency.

Comment: Thanks for that correction, Dilip. I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: @JasonR Hmm, but the cosines Dilip is referring to arent phase-modulated so isnt this a case of apples and oranges? Also, by 'lines' are we talking about loud tones due to the mixing process, or by notches in the spectrum? For CDMA spectra (where there is a repetition of chips) I can see 'notches' in the spectrum and a certain periodicity. What do we mean here by 'lines'?

Comment: @Mohammad: The cosines that he's referring to are the *modulating* signals, so they are directing the phase of the signal that is being *modulated*. "Spectral lines" in this context refers to discrete components; on a power spectrum plot, they would appear to be "pickets" sticking up out of the spectrum.

Comment: @JasonR Oops - yes true. However, are not the pickets due to the harmonics of the mixings different than the 'periodic appearance' of a non-white phases modulated signal?

Comment: In this theoretical scenario, there is no "mixing". Think of the modulated signal as $x(t) = \cos(\omega_c + 2 \pi h m(t))$, where $m(t)$ is the modulating signal. The phase of x(t) varies proportionally to $m(t)$. You might be thinking of more practical effects observed from use of mixers for frequency translation or amplitude modulation. This discussion isn't at that "real" of a level.

Comment: @JasonR Ok, so are we saying that the spectrum of $x(t)=cos(ωc+2πhm(t))$ where $m(t) = periodic chip sequence$ has spectral periodicity, while $x(t)=cos(ωc+2πhm(t))$ where $m(t) = cos(ω1t)+cos(ω2t)$ will also have periodic spectrum even though m(t) is not periodic? (And while the former appears periodic without loud 'lines' the latter does in fact have loud 'lines'? Is that what is being said? Want to make sure I get it.

Comment: If the _modulating signal_ is $\cos(\omega_1 t)$, there are lines in the spectrum at $\omega_c \pm n\omega_1$ for _all_ $n$ with heights decreasing rapidly as we get away from $\omega_c$.  There are also (smaller) lines at $2\omega_c \pm m\omega_1$ etc.  If $\omega_c = N\omega_1$ with $N \gg 1$ an integer, then the line at $\omega_c + N\omega_1$ has negligibly small height but _adds_ to to the small line at $2\omega_c$ and so on.  If $\omega_c$ is not a harmonic of $\omega_1$ but $\omega_c \approx N\omega_1$, then the negligibly small line at $\omega_c + N\omega_1$ is _close to_ (continued)

Comment: (continued) but _not exactly_ at $2\omega_c$.  Similarly the negligibly small line at $2\omega_c - N\omega_1$ is close to but not exactly at $\omega_c$ and this gives rise to _clutter_.  For the case of $\cos(\omega_1 t) + \cos(\omega_2 t)$ with $\omega_1/\omega_2$ irrational, there are lines at $l\omega_c \pm m\omega_1 \pm n\omega_2$ of small height and the locations of these components form a _dense set_ giving essentially continuous low-level spectral clutter in addition to the _strong_ lines at $\omega \pm m\omega_1 \pm n\omega_2$ for _small_ $m$ and $n$.

Comment: If the _modulating signal_ is periodic with Fourier series $\sum_i a_i \cos(i\omega_1t)$ _and_ the carrier is a harmonic of $\omega_1$, then there are spectral lines at $l\omega_c+\sum_i\pm m_i(i\omega_1)$, and the line corresponding to $\omega_c+2(\omega_1)+0(2\omega_1)+ 0(3\omega_1) + \cdots$ is at the _same_ frequency as $\omega_c+0(\omega_1)+1(2\omega_1)+0(3\omega_1)+\cdots$.  In other words, we have a pure line spectrum and the phase modulated signal is also periodic with fundamental frequency $\omega_1$ (but negligibly little energy anywhere except in the vicinity of $\omega_c$).

Comment: @DilipSarwate Ah! I see it now... I just simulated it - How do we arrive at those multiples though? (ωc±nω, 2ωc±mω1, etc)? I tried going a course derivation ... are you doing a taylor expansion on the cosine term cos(ωc+2πhm(t)) , or is there some other method?... Thanks!